# How to change/customize Copy.com Nautilus overlay icons?

Tags: nautilus, icons, copy.com

The grey Copy.com overlay icons, which indicate a file's synchronization or upload status in Nautilus, appear less integrated with the Ubuntu look and feel, compared to the icons that were used by the UbuntuOne client.

How can the Copy.com overlay icons be customized?

[image: Copy.com Default Nautilus Overlay Icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these steps customize the Copy.com Nautilus overlay icons...**

1. First install the Copy.com Nauilus overlay emblems...

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/copy/x86_64/CopyCmd Overlay install
   ```

   (Replace `/usr/share/copy/` with the location where you installed Copy. Also, replace `x86_64` with `x86` if you have a 32 bit computer).
2. Replace the default emblems with custom icons.  In this example, I've used the icons from the Humanity icon theme, which were used by UbuntuOne...

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/emblems/24/emblem-ubuntuone-unsynchronized.svg /usr/share/nautilus-copy/emblems/emblem-overlayerror.png
   sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/emblems/24/emblem-ubuntuone-synchronized.svg /usr/share/nautilus-copy/emblems/emblem-overlayinsync.png
   sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/emblems/24/emblem-ubuntuone-updating.svg /usr/share/nautilus-copy/emblems/emblem-overlaypending.png
   ```

   (If you like, you can also replace the progress bar icons located in `/usr/share/nautilus-copy/emblems/`).
3. The overlay icons in Nautilus should automatically change; if they do not, you can refresh your Nautilus view by pressing F5.

   [image: Copy.com UbuntuOne Nautilus Overlay Icons]
4. Finally, if you found this useful, and are so inclined, kindly use my [Copy.com](https://copy.com?r=dbRPen) referral link (https://copy.com?r=dbRPen) to register for this service -- both you and I will get an *extra* 5GB of storage space.

**Tip...**

You can get pretty creative with these overlay emblems.  Here is an example using the Copy.com crane logo.  Note that the icon image does not have to be a specific pixel size, because it will automatically be scaled to fit.  Also, you can use other image formats such as *.png or *.svg.  The icon used in this example is 256x256 pixel PNG image and was automatically resized by Nautilus accordingly...

[image: Copy.com Logo Nautilus Overlay Icons]

**To revert your overlay icon changes and return to the default Copy.com emblems, simply execute...**

```
sudo /usr/share/copy/x86_64/CopyCmd Overlay install
```